# C++ Compile Error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, token

I can't figure out why I am getting these errors when I try to compile.  I've never encountered the 'expected _ before _ token' error, but I believe they're common (if not feel free to enlighten me).

> pe4.cpp: In function `'int main()'`:
>   
> pe4.cpp:18: error: expected `')'` before `';'` token
>   
> pe4.cpp:18: error: expected `';'` before `')'` token
>   
> pe4.cpp:45: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before `'{'` token
>   
> pe4.cpp:51: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before `'{'` token
>   
> pe4.cpp:57: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before `'{'` token

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printStar(int);
void printSpace(int);
void printNewLine();

int main()
{
    int side, i, j;

    if (i=0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter side: " << endl;
        cin << side;

        if (side < 3 || side > 20)
        {
            cout << "Out of Bounds!!!"
            return 0;
        }

        printStar(side);
        printNewLine();

        {
            printStar(1);
            printSpace(side-2);
            printStar(1);
            printNewLine();
        }

        printStar(side);
        printNewLine();
    }

    void printStar(int a)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
            cout << "*";
    }

    void printSpace(int a)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
            cout << " ";
    }

    void printNewLine()
    {
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no `;` at the end of the `cout << "Out of Bounds!!!"` line.

You have `if (i=0; i < 2; i++)`; that should be `for (i=0;...`.

You have `cin << side`; that should be `cin >> side`.

You have defined your function bodies *inside* `main()`; they should live outside.

Comment: Heh, I was reading too fast. I didn't even catch the `if` => `for`.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining your functions printStar(), etc,  inside your main() definition. Move those functions outside of main()'s closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

The closing  `}` of the `int main()` method needs to go before `void printStart(int a)`.

Also, you need a `;` at the end of `cout << "Out of Bound!!!"`